# JQuery wrapAll, append, remove to move elements and add a div

Tags: jquery, append, wrapall

I am trying to move, and possibly remove some elements, along with wrapping the updated HTML with a 'div'. I have to use an equal count, that I have been able to calculate (let's assume I want to split it into 5 each till there are any leftover li tags)

Tried .wrapAll and .append, .remove etc. but some of the HTML is getting removed before I can update.

If class='x' exists, the HTML is to be moved accordingly (without changing the content or order of lis) but we just don't account for it in the splitting/couting of `<ul>` per 5 elements.

Thus, there may be more than one 'li class='x' in the updated HTML, but originally there is always only one per `<ul>` tag (and it is always the first element in the original HTML).

Current HTML:

```
 <ul>   
        <li class="x">First</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three   </li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>    
        <li class="x">Second</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>    
        <li class="x">Third</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
    </ul>
```

Move the

previous  based on a specific count. 
Add a div 'wrapper' class to these ul
Remove any left over  tags

Desired HTML result:

```
<ul>    
    <li class="x">First</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>    
    <li class="x">Second</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>   
</ul>
<ul>    
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>   
</ul>   
<ul> 
    <li class="x">Third</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Update:** Changed the code to reflect the comments by OP.

```
function splitEm() {
    var $uls = $("ul");
    var $last = $uls.last();
    var $lis = $uls.children("li").detach();
    var points = [], count=0, prevIndex = 0;
    $.each($lis, function (index, item) {
        var i =  $(item).is(".x")?0:1;
        count += i;
        if(count%5 == 0 && i) {
            points.push(index - (prevIndex)?0:1;
            prevIndex = index;
        } 
    });

    if(prevIndex != $lis.length) {
        points.push($lis.length - prevIndex);
    }

    $.each(points, function(index, item) {
        var $curUL = null;
        if(index < $uls.length) { 
            $curUL = $uls.eq(index);
        }   else {
            $curUL = $("<ul/>").insertAfter($last);
            $last = $curUL;
        }
        $curUL.append($lis.splice(0, item));
    });
}

$(splitEm);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yd14gw5d/4/

Comment: Hi. I tried it, but it's not working when I change the number of elements to less than 5 in the first 3 <ul>s. As I still need it split equally as a group of 5 (till there are less than or equal to 5 left in the last ul). So in that case, I have to move the elements from second <ul> into first. For instance  http://jsfiddle.net/yd14gw5d/1/

Comment: @Amy Updated the answer, Can you check if this what you are looking at?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! It is working as expected and I'm just running some more scenarios to verify the same. Just one last thing. I don't want it to count 'class=x' in the 5 results, and am trying to apply your logic to the same, just not sure where to put the check for the class to exclude would be...

Comment: You mean the li elements with the class x should be in the UL's that they were in? If so how many li's should a UL have if it already contains an li with `class=x`

Comment: the class='x' also has to move accordingly, I just don't count it in the 5 <lis> that are being accounted in the split/moving. If class='x' exists, we move it but we just don't account for it in the $uls.length to split..

Comment: If you achieved what you wanted to do, I would suggest posting your code as an another answer (and maybe selecting it as the final answer) so that someone else might benefit from that..

Comment: almost there, but I am still trying to figure out how to split the li tags only counting  nonclass=x li elements.I have updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63433/discussion-between-chandu-and-amy).